# Реализация именованного канала сообщений WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, pipes, sendmessage

Помогите - нужен пример с пояснениями или ссылка на него 
Для реализации обмена сообщениями через CreateNamedPipe.

Желательно, чтоб пример содержал создание пайпа, запись сообщения в него, считывание сообщения из него, его закрытие.

Все это желательно на русском или немецком, т.к. на анг. плохо понятно

Спасибо!

Comment: Я так понял что свойство должно быть PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE

Comment: Вы вряд ли изучите их по ответам на SO, лучше найдите что-нибудь почитать по теме. Нюансов там хватает. Я бы дал вам пример кода, но это физически сложно, выдрать все специфические части и привести его в какую-то форму примера. Его еще и тестировать нужно после такого. Нереально, извините.

Comment: мне даже самый базовый пример сссссгодится

Comment: Базовый пример есть в [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/using-pipes), и для сервера, и для клиента.

Comment: @freim а на русском нет?

Comment: Ну вот например, "Программирование в сетях Microsoft Windows", Э.Джонс, Д.Оланд. Неплохая книжка. Она 2002 года издания, но возможно, вам ее удастся найти хотя бы в электронном виде. Наверняка еще какая-то литература есть, ищите.

Comment: @freim огромное спасибо! Отличная книга